# Airflow Trigger Dag and wait until response status

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

We have recently adopted Airflow as our orchestrator tool. We want to create controller DAG and some target DAGs to have better control over which DAG run. Controller DAG would be like the one to start other target DAGs consecutively.

I used TriggerDagRunOperator, however, it always return successful as it's job is only trigger and not wait for result.

I expect something like waiting until its state changes from running to success, fail or etc. then trigger dag on downstream or stop others to be triggered (according to result of upstream one). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you had a look at [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.html)? Quite a lot of people use it to control their DAG dependencies i.e. [Lyft](https://eng.lyft.com/running-apache-airflow-at-lyft-6e53bb8fccff)

Comment: Actually I did not look at it. But it seems like will handle my problem.Thanks!